# How to make a 1:1 type map of an object literal with a new type of value as a function return implicitly?

Tags: typescript

Currently I'm able to get a union of the key and values of each object literal passed into a function.

e.g.

```
interface StaticClass<T = any> {
  new (...args: any[]): T
}
type RecordOfStaticClasses = Record<string, StaticClass>;
type RecordOfInstances<T extends RecordOfStaticClasses> = Record<keyof T, InstanceType<T[keyof T]>>;

const transformObjLiteral = <T extends RecordOfStaticClasses>(input: T): RecordOfInstances<T> => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) => [key, new value])) as RecordOfInstances<T>;
}

// Transformation
class Cat {
  asleep: boolean;
}
class Zebra {
  hoofLength: number;
}
transformObjLiteral({ myCat: Cat }).myCat.asleep // works if only 1 key is added
transformObjLiteral({ myCat: Cat, myZebra: Zebra }).myCat.asleep // Error: Property 'asleep' does not exist on type 'Cat | Zebra'!
```

As can be seen from above, it works well when only a object literal with 1 key is passed. However when adding two keys it cant get specific due to the possibility of a Union type. I know I can use Generics (e.g. `transformObjLiteral<{ myCat: Cat }>({ myCat: Cat })`) but I hope to accomplish this implicitly based on the argument by itself. Is this posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `Record`, use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) directly to keep the association between individual keys `K` and their `InstanceType<T[K]>`.

```
type RecordOfInstances<T extends RecordOfStaticClasses> = {
  [K in keyof T]: InstanceType<T[K]>
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjmYCDCAbOAZ0IB4AVZAXmThAE8A%20ZAbwFgAoZZECAd2QAUAOhFwoAc0IAuGvQDaAXQCUMshwC%20HMHQAOKAEoQEAeygATAPIx0mbPiKEIhKskMnzJQmCihxAGjQMLFwCYgYAbi1dAyNTSxgASRAvWiRSCggAD0gQM2c3OKsbYPtiJyZqNk5kOQBpZFBkAGsIOmMYZDIFGSSUkCQyaPI6hQYNDg4TZLBkb1pCGFMAWwsAIwArABlgSCg4PBdyZCycvNdY8yKgu1DHQgYBUB0AVzBVFXP3eN6MfqdyCpMKpcKAQMDPKAgZBrdZGMBCGBQYxLACi4B8TgEMLhQgg6OAmKeryUQiWcB0AgEchadACADd9s8IMoqExqa0Ajx%20Ay8EzlEoaPkLt9pql-mQIuN2BwAPQyzp7ZKLKBkrDGECTW7IHCYFgcLhEPAQCA6ACEMlWxmMRtokXYmnYCC1AC0IKs9nrqgALK0wTZ48RgL3m7jPJaraB2h1zJXLGHbXb7ATMZBLOg6t7a3XqElpjNCQ3GnTIOXIXimJrOYAddV4OjIACMzVaDWccDMZggZi0ioWcY2CegSZTecwMgzATTrvdcBk049OdJ6cwBcIRpNJflKKgSKgMgACki9FBtMgAOSFk1n5BmYxObjGGZZYBeZDq2bRc8Z5AAH2Q87gM9TSAA)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this and providing a playground!